# JDBC can't pull data rows while using MYSQL query with WHERE statement

Tags: java, mysql, database, maven, jdbc

I'm using this Maven dependency to execute Mysql queries:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

And this is my java code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://...", "root", "xxxxx");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM User WHERE userName='username'");
    while (res.next()) {
        String s = res.getString("id");
    }
```

I can pull data with simple queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM USER;
```

But

If I want to execute above query with WHERE statement the ResultSet.Next is always false!

Please help.
And thanks in advance.

Comment: you had better use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement`.

Comment: Does your table actually have a user called `username`?

Comment: @mustafacil Thanks I'll try it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen while executing the query using IDE I'm getting the correct data.

Comment: @NaelAbdeljawad You did not answer my question.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't.

Comment: I changed my code and used preaparedStatement: 

PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `DeviceSession` WHERE `userId`= 'e-b10d-cda9bdbde5dd'");
  boolean isResult = st.execute();
  if (isResult) {
   ResultSet res = st.getResultSet();
   while (res.next()) {
    String s = res.getString(1);
    System.out.println(s);
   }
  }

Didn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to make sure that string you are writing in the condition is case sensitive

you can use

> statement =con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from User WHERE  userName=
>   ?"); statement.setString(1, userName);